# How can a penalty charge notice result in adverse impact on one’s credit score?

Tags: england-and-wales, penalty

If one totally neglects and disregards penalty charge notices and the ensuing proceedings etc can it result in adverse effect upon one’s credit score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

In the UK, if the "penalty charge" matter proceeds to a successful court judgment, which isn't settled by the judgment debtor, then the credit reference agencies will collect and report this judgment as adverse information about creditworthiness.

However, the mere non-payment of a "penalty charge" demand will not typically be reported to credit reference agencies or affect a credit score.

Comment: A Transport for London Penalty Charge Notice (e.g. for ignoring ULEZ) doesn't ultimately land in court for a CCJ. The Traffic Enforcement Centre issues a 'warrant of control' but, according to TfL, "this does not result in a County Court Judgement (CCJ) being registered against your name or address. In addition, it does not affect your credit rating in any way."

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### The same way any unpaid debt does

The government can, and does, report overdue debts to credit reporting agencies and they report them along with any other unpaid debts you might have.

They government has an advantage over private creditors as they don’t need to prove the debt in court and have access to [more](https://www.nsw.gov.au/money-and-taxes/fines-and-fees/fines/difficulty-paying-your-fine/what-happens-if-you-dont-pay-your-fine#:%7E:text=serious%20recovery%20action.-,Recovery%20action,your%20bank%20account%20or%20wages.) enforcement actions, like cancelling your licence and registration.

To be clear, the fine is not final while you are contesting it in court but once that is done, or your opportunity to do so has passed, the fine, and any additional enforcement costs, is a proven liquidated debt.